# OpenGl Result difference In Xcode and visual studio

Tags: c, xcode, macos, opengl, opengl-compat

I wrote a simple OpenGL code, and it worked normally in visual Studio.
But when it was moved to Xcode. it was a compilation success, but the results were different. There are nothing.

I only changed OpenGL, GLUT header file.

I suspect that the range of `gluPerspective` is different in Xcode, but I don't know the exact cause.

How is it workable?

Here is my code In xcode

```
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double RotAngle = 0.0;  
void OctPyramid(void)
{
    int N = 8;
    double angle = 2 * 3.1415 / N;
    int i;
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        glVertex3f(cos(i * angle), -1.0, sin(i * angle));
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(cos(i * angle), -1.0, sin(i * angle));
    }
    glEnd();
}
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -6.0);
    glRotatef(RotAngle, 0, 1, 0);
    glTranslatef(2.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    OctPyramid();

    glFlush();
}


void IncAngle(void)
{
    RotAngle = RotAngle + 0.08;
    if (RotAngle > 360.0)
        RotAngle = RotAngle - 360.0;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA);
    glutCreateWindow("main");
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45, 1.0, 0.0, 10.0);


    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutIdleFunc(IncAngle);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: *"But when it was moved to Xcode ... the results were different."* - What is the difference?

Comment: It's hard to believe that an OpenGL or glut method would behave differently on different compilers. But when you switch hardware or OS, there can be differences. E.g. gamma correction might be different.

Comment: Compilation succeeded, but unlike Visual Basic, nothing is seen.  Just black screen

Answer (score 3):

The distance to the near plane `zNear` and the distance to the far plane `zFar` have to be greater than 0:

Set `zNear` greater than *0.0*:

<s>`gluPerspective(45, 1.0, 0.0, 10.0);`</s>
`gluPerspective(45, 1.0, 0.1, 10.0);`

Note, [`gluPerspective`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) sets a projection matrix like the following:

```
ta = tan(fovy / 2)
a  = aspect
n  = zNear
f  = zFar

x:    1/(ta*a)  0     0              0
y:    0         1/ta  0              0
z:    0         0    -(f+n)/(f-n)   -1
t:    0         0    -2*f*n/(f-n)    0
```

If `zNear = 0` this leads to:

```
x:    1/(ta*a)  0     0    0
y:    0         1/ta  0    0
z:    0         0    -1   -1
t:    0         0     0    0
```

If a [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) is transformed by such a matrix, then the `z` component of the result will be always equal the `w` component.
After the [Perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide) the `z` component of the normalized device coordinate is 1, regardless of the coordinate.
This means that all the vertex coordinates of the geometry are "projected" to the same depth, all the geometry has the maximum depth of 1.0.
Because of that `zNear` has to be greater than 0.0, else the behavior is not specified and depends on the internal implementation of the library.

Comment: Thanks It works well In Xcode.
Could you tell me why zNear zFar diffrent in Xcode and in Viusal Studio?

Comment: @ジョユンサン  I don't know the difference in implementation of the libraries, but a near plan of 0.0 causes undefined behavior. Each implementation may handle this different.